# Where does xcode store project file locations / recent projects?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

When you load up xcode it tells what the recent files/projects you worked on are. Where does Xcode store this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they're stored in `com.apple.Xcode NSRecentXCProjectDocuments`. This is part of the "Expert" preferences, which are not exposed through the GUI.

This may vary slightly based on what you are trying to do. For example, `$ defaults write com.apple.Xcode NSRecentDocumentsLimit 20` will show 20 recent projects (rather than the default 10).

As for accessing the list itself, the only thing I could find was the following code in the [Quick Search Box](http://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/source/browse/trunk/Vermilion/Modules/RecentDocuments/RecentDocumentsSource.m?r=545) source code (though it looks like it might require an external library):

```
 if ([appIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.apple.Xcode"]) {
          NSArray *recentXCodeProjects
            = GTMCFAutorelease(
                CFPreferencesCopyValue(CFSTR("NSRecentXCProjectDocuments"),
                                       (CFStringRef)appIdentifier,
                                       kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
                                       kCFPreferencesAnyHost));
```

Comment: I want to use it to load a list of recent projects in my application that they can click on and then it will open it. Is there a way to do thi?

Comment: The closest thing I could find that looks like it allows for access to the list itself is in the qsb-mac source on Google. I have added this info to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what the question meant but i was looking to add image and needed the project external directory so this is how i found it in a really simple way:

you can see the full path in the right  side of the screen when you click like mine was 
images:

```
/Users/user_name/Desktop/app_name
```

the first / can tell you it's a unix based system

and you can use the finder in mac to find this location. That's what it's for.